# c# Xamarin Android Background Timer dispose

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timer, background

When my app goes in background, a timer starts ( in `OnStop()` override)

This time just perform a query every 10 seconds.

If the result "x", thanI create a notification, and dispose timer. Now I can either click the notification or resume the app.

But if i want to use the App resuming it, it get stuck in the "stopped" layout, and I see timer doesn't die (from console).

I tried to stop it in `OnResume()`, `OnStart()`, `OnRestart()`but none of these get called, timer still goes and app crashes.

I'm pretty sure my way to check database update in background is very bad, but I would like to use this way.

The times is made like this:

```
public class TimerExampleState
    {
        public int counter = 0;
        public Timer tmr;
    }
protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
            GlobalVar.KillTimer = 0;
            StuffInStop();
        }
public void StuffInStop()
        {

                TimerExampleState s = new TimerExampleState();
                TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(CheckStatus);
                Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelegate, s, 1000, 10000);
                s.tmr = timer;

                while (s.tmr != null)
                    Thread.Sleep(0);


        }


public async void CheckStatus(Object state)
        {
            TimerExampleState s = (TimerExampleState)state;
            s.counter++;
            if (s.counter == 2)
            {
                int x = await AsyncIntCheck();
                if (GlobalVar.KillTimer == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("disposing of timer...");
                    s.tmr.Dispose();
                    s.tmr = null;
                }
                s.counter = 1;
            }
        }
```

the `AsyncIntCheck` is the fucntion checking for updates (it is a int function because later it will return the number of updatet parts).

As you can imagine I've a global int, when I create notification, i set `GlobalVar.KillTimer` to 1 and timer get killed.

I hope I wrote everything needed, just for redundancies, I want kill timer when user resume app.

Thanks.

Comment: This code will not run. You cannot run a timer in background specially in iOS. You need to take platform specific actions (that might even be impossible in some platforms).

Comment: This code do works, I'm using it and works in my smartphone. It's even a xamarin walkthrough (i'm interested in android only). The only things that I can't achieve, is killing the timer when user resume activity.

Comment: you said setting global variable kills the timer, so what exactly the problem?

Comment: Check in what thread you create a timer and what thread tries to kill it. If threads are different timer will not get killed.

Comment: The problem is: When user resume app, timer still counting, and app just stop and eventually crashes. The "on resume", "on start", restart, function are not called, and functions outside this events can't see user action. 
I solved this problem creating a service, I will post my answer, as soon as I see is totally working.
Thanks for help.